# Which ATI driver should I use for a Radeon Xpress 200M?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, ati, graphics

So my laptop that I'm using with Ubuntu 11.10 so far is working great.  The thing is that in the driver on my system info says its using Gallium 0.4 on ATI RS480. 
My Laptop is old and is using the IGP of the ATI Radeon Xpress 200M.

I looked around and not understanding whats going on, but it seems there is 2 versions.  The xerver-xorg-video-ati and the fglrx.

Question 1:
Is the Gallium driver showing in the system info is the open source driver (xerver-xord-video-ati) mentioned?

Question 2:
Is there a point in using the fglrx version?

Question 3:
Should I stay with what I have or should I get fglrx?

Side note: Upon checking one of the questions recommended, I did run the unity support test and Unity 3d supported does show "yes" along with every other test.

Comment: 1.Yes, 2.No, your card is not Supported anymore, 3.Stay with what you have, you don't have that much of a choice anyways.

Comment: That works.  I suppose though that if I ever did get a newer laptop and it had an ATI graphics in there, I would have to use fglrx if it was anything like the 6000 series?

Comment: Yes, for better performance on newer cards use fglrx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uri Herrera's answers are correct.

Note that some Xpress 200M have weird oddball bugs and glitches, that are only solved by adjusting the AGP values in BIOS.  But sounds like -ati is working fine so no worries.